# Assumption made in Proof of System of ODEs with Repeated Roots

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

In a system of ODEs with a repeated root, what brings one to ***assume*** that the form of the equation is

\begin{align}
y(t)=v(t)e^{rt}
\end{align}

where $r$ is the repeated root. I get that multiplying $ce^{rt}$ by $t$ yields a second, linearly independent solution, but how would you arrive at the above supposition intuitively?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order

Answer (score 1):

In ODE and PDE research, sometimes a "guess and check" method is employed. Multiplying by $ce^{rt}$ works nicely.

Consider the ODE $y'=y$ with initial condition $y(0)=k$. Without knowing the solution is the exponential, we want to find a function (more generally, a family of functions) that is equal to its own derivative. There is *only* one such function that is equal to its own derivative *everywhere* (not just almost everywhere).

This is perhaps remarkable, because it is essentially saying out of the uncountably many functions in $C^1$, only one of them is equal to its own derivative. The proof of this fact however requires some justification, and I remember correctly is not an entirely trivial proof.

For a system of ODEs, the solution $y(t)=v(t)e^{rt}$ works. We can check to see that is unique (under some initial conditions). However, a priori, without knowing the solution to the system takes this form, we would have to use a lot of machinery to rule out other possible functions as solutions.